# WordPress check if user logged in works only after some time

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

[image: Here is picture how my service works]

I'm working on page: http://mytengo.com . It's service with ads. When user click +Add new ad, he will be automatically redirected to login page (if he's not logged in). When he log in, He should see New Ad page, But now it's redirecting me once more to Login page (is_user_logged_in = false), and in the login page it redirecting me to Profile page (is_user_logged_in = true).

But when I log in and open this page after 5 minutes it works fine, I can Add new ad. How to solve this problem? I try to change the code a lot of times, so I think the problem is in something else.

```
global $redux_demo;
$hide_map = $redux_demo['hide-map'];

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $login = $redux_demo['login'];
   wp_redirect( $login ); 
   exit;

} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache, maybe something remained.

Comment: I cleared cache 10x, this problem I've from 2 months.